# Start Process Acts Differently in Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

I have batch file for opening Dataloader application which is provided by Salesforce. When I double click to the bat file, it opens normally. However, when I use start process action in Blue Prism, it acts different. Do you have any idea why I am facing that?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The .bat file provided by Salesforce most likely launches Dataloader with some program arguments.

Open the .bat file to confirm this, and then copy the arguments into the `Arguments` input of the Blue Prism action.